# React-native-camera error with Expo: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'CameraManager.Aspect')

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, expo

I cannot seem to get react-native-camera working in Expo. Here is a screenshot of the error I am receiving:

[image: Camera error]

The error originates on line 62 of react-native-camera `index.js` which is calling `NativeModules.CameraManager`. Does this have something to do with expo not having access to some native APIs?

Steps already taken:

- react-native link react-native-camera
- watchman watch-del-all
- rm -rf node_modules && npm install
- rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*
- npm start -- --reset-cache

Restarting the build

I also created a regular react native app via `react-native init` and was able to properly set up react-native-camera without any issues.

Comment: Is it an ejected projecet? If so, are you using react-native-navigation? I'm having this same problem, on Android.

Answer (score 3):

I reached out to the Expo team directly and this was the response I received:

> custom native modules are not supported in expo unless you eject
>
> see the sdk api reference section of docs to see what native apis we
>   expose https://docs.expo.io/versions/v16.0.0/index.html

[Answer from expo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zujDn.png)

Comment: How do you "eject"

Comment: https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/EJECTING.md

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `expo` `camera` from:

```
import { Camera, Permissions } from 'expo';
```

Take a look at:

```
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/camera.html
```

Comment: In recent versions of expo SDK, you need to use import { Camera } from 'expo-camera' and import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to use the camera with Expo.
In this case you can use the Expo Camera package with comes with the Expo API

SDK API ReferenceCamera:
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/camera.html

> As background info - Expo and native modules: React-Native is able to
>   use native app code and access native features, but it needs to be
>   'linked' via the native app code e.g. the POD file. In the case of
>   Expo, the native app is already written and only executes your React
>   Native code. With Expo, linking is only possible when you 'eject' or
>   'detach' from the original code, which does only make sense in some
>   cases.